# Vagrant-Libvirt Hanging on SSH Connection

Tags: ssh, vagrant, libvirt

When I run `vagrant up` my setup hangs when trying to connect to the VM with the insecure_private_key. It keeps trying and trying with output similar to this:

```
 INFO retryable: Retryable exception raised: #<Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer>
 INFO ssh: Attempting to connect to SSH...
 INFO ssh:   - Host: 192.168.121.80
 INFO ssh:   - Port: 22
 INFO ssh:   - Username: vagrant
 INFO ssh:   - Password? false
 INFO ssh:   - Key Path: ["/home/users/swalter/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"]
DEBUG ssh: == Net-SSH connection debug-level log START ==
DEBUG ssh: D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.236064 #24396] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[3fa468444c28]: establishing connection to 192.168.121.80:22
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.236454 #24396] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[3fa468444c28]: connection established
I, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.236614 #24396]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[3fa468444264]: negotiating protocol version
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.262088 #24396] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[3fa468444264]: remote is `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3'
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.262176 #24396] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[3fa468444264]: local is `SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_2.9.1 x86_64-linux'
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.263494 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: read 840 bytes
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.263615 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: received packet nr 0 type 20 len 836
I, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.263706 #24396]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3fa4683ed9c8]: got KEXINIT from server
I, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.263819 #24396]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3fa4683ed9c8]: sending KEXINIT
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.264016 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: queueing packet nr 0 type 20 len 2020
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.264098 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: sent 2024 bytes
I, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.264130 #24396]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3fa4683ed9c8]: negotiating algorithms
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.264253 #24396] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3fa4683ed9c8]: negotiated:
* kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
* host_key: ssh-rsa
* encryption_server: aes128-cbc
* encryption_client: aes128-cbc
* hmac_client: hmac-sha1
* hmac_server: hmac-sha1
* compression_client: none
* compression_server: none
* language_client:
* language_server:
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.264283 #24396] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3fa4683ed9c8]: exchanging keys
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.264478 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: queueing packet nr 1 type 34 len 20
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.264533 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: sent 24 bytes
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.265762 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: read 152 bytes
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.265844 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: received packet nr 1 type 31 len 148
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.267446 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: queueing packet nr 2 type 32 len 140
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.267521 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: sent 144 bytes
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.269986 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: read 720 bytes
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.270066 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: received packet nr 2 type 33 len 700
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.271360 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: queueing packet nr 3 type 21 len 20
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.271432 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: sent 24 bytes
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.271491 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: received packet nr 3 type 21 len 12
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.271752 #24396] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fa468414758]: beginning authentication of `vagrant'
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.271858 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: queueing packet nr 4 type 5 len 28
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.271905 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: sent 52 bytes
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.311362 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: read 52 bytes
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.311453 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: received packet nr 4 type 6 len 28
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.311547 #24396] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fa468414758]: trying none
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.311650 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: queueing packet nr 5 type 50 len 44
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.311709 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: sent 68 bytes
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.312042 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: read 84 bytes
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.312109 #24396] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fa468444868]: received packet nr 5 type 51 len 60
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.312177 #24396] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fa468414758]: allowed methods: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.312226 #24396] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.none[3fa46845d0d4]: none failed
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.312276 #24396] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fa468414758]: trying publickey
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.312520 #24396] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[3fa46846971c]: connecting to ssh-agent
D, [2015-10-13T15:04:11.312672 #24396] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[3fa46846971c]: sending agent request 1 len 44

DEBUG ssh: == Net-SSH connection debug-level log END ==
```

If I take the ip address it's attempting to ssh with, open a new terminal, and `ssh -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key vagrant@192.168.121.80` it works just fine.

How am I able to ssh to the instance but not this vagrant process?

Here is my  config file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.box = "centos/6"
config.ssh.insert_key = false
# Controller node
config.vm.define "vbit00" do |n|
    n.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.122.10", netmask: "255.255.255.0"
    n.vm.provider :libvirt do |libvirt|
        libvirt.driver = "kvm"
        libvirt.connect_via_ssh = false
        libvirt.username = "root"
        libvirt.storage_pool_name = "default"
        libvirt.memory = 2048
    end
end

# Storage nodes
config.vm.define "vbit06" do |n|
    n.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.122.20", netmask: "255.255.255.0"
    n.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.123.20", netmask: "255.255.255.0"
    n.vm.provider :libvirt do |libvirt|
        libvirt.driver = "kvm"
        libvirt.connect_via_ssh = false
        libvirt.username = "root"
        libvirt.storage_pool_name = "default"
        libvirt.storage :file, :size=> '11G'
        libvirt.memory = 1024
    end
end
config.vm.define "vbit07" do |n|
    n.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.122.21", netmask: "255.255.255.0"
    n.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.123.21", netmask: "255.255.255.0"
    n.vm.provider :libvirt do |libvirt|
        libvirt.driver = "kvm"
        libvirt.connect_via_ssh = false
        libvirt.username = "root"
        libvirt.storage_pool_name = "default"
        libvirt.storage :file, :size=> '11G'
        libvirt.memory = 1024
    end
end

# Compute nodes
config.vm.define "vbit10" do |n|
    n.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.122.30", netmask: "255.255.255.0"
    n.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.123.30", netmask: "255.255.255.0"
    n.vm.provider :libvirt do |libvirt|
        libvirt.driver = "kvm"
        libvirt.connect_via_ssh = false
        libvirt.username = "root"
        libvirt.storage_pool_name = "default"
        libvirt.storage :file, :size=>"5G"
        libvirt.memory = 4096
    end
end
config.vm.define "vbit11" do |n|
    n.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.122.31", netmask: "255.255.255.0"
    n.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.123.31", netmask: "255.255.255.0"
    n.vm.provider :libvirt do |libvirt|
        libvirt.driver = "kvm"
        libvirt.connect_via_ssh = false
        libvirt.username = "root"
        libvirt.storage_pool_name = "default"
        libvirt.storage :file, :size=>'5G'
        libvirt.memory = 4096
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Whatever is responsible in vagrant for port forwarding the local host's 2222 port to the remote host 22 port wasn't working. I set up my own port with ssh like this: `ssh -L 2222:192.168.121.24:22 127.0.0.1`

Where 192.168.121.24 was an IP address of a VM that was trying to boot. I knew the IP address because I was watching the logs. Strange thing is, however, is that after I destroyed that VM and recreated it, it worked. I didn't need to recreate the port forward with the IP address of the new VM. It's like as soon as vagrant sees it working once, it stops checking the port forward.

Either way, it's working now but only in the terminal where I created the port forward. I suppose a more system-wide port forward could be done with iptables or firewalld.